# SharePoint Workflow 2013 collect data from user

Tags: sharepoint-2013

This feature was available with SharePoint 2010, how can I get data from user with SharePoint 2013 ?

Comment: I suspect that you have to create a task and then pause the workflow until the user completes the task. Or split the workflow up and get the user to interact with a list or form.

Answer (score 0):

This is no longer available in 2013.

You can create a workflow using the 2010 platform option and get this functionality back.